# How to plot mod (absolute) function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want plot this mod function in MATLAB:

```
|L*x|<=0.05
L=[1 0];
x=[x1 x2];
```

where `x1` is along the x axis and `x2` is along the y axis.

How do I do this?

Comment: i checked that already....:(

Comment: `mod` and `abs` are two completely different things.